# Least Squares: I obtain convergence only changing '+' into a '-'

Tags: python, sign, least-squares, convergence

During the least squares computation:

```
 x = N(-1) * At * Q(-1) * (yo -b)
```

Instead of doing:

```
 Xnew = Xold + x[0] 

 Ynew = Yold + x[1]
```

In order to obtain the convergence I have to change the '+' into a '-':

```
 Xnew = Xold - x[0] 

 Ynew = Yold - x[1]
```

Does anyone know the reason? I am doing something wrong?

Here is my Python Code:

```py
import numpy as np
x_m = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(N_matrix),A_matrix.T)
x_mat = np.dot(corr_m,np.linalg.pinv(Q_matrix))
x_matrix = np.dot(corr_mat,delta_y)    
xnew.iloc[0,0] = xold.iloc[0,0] - x_matrix[0]
xnew.iloc[0,1] = xold.iloc[0,1] - x_matrix[1]
```

Comment: You should include the original equation that you are trying to solve and explain your notation. Also, there are a number of things in your code that we don't know what they are. Without this context, how is one supposed to know what you have in mind?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.